# UIImage Add Grey tranparency

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want to do the following:

[image]

As you can see one image (selected) does not have a grey fade and the other (nonselected item) does **not**.

I have tried multiple solutions. Including coloring the images with a grey color

```
    - (UIImage *)colorizeImage:(UIImage *)image withColor:(UIColor *)color {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -area.size.height);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, area, image.CGImage);

    [color set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, area);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, area, image.CGImage);

    UIImage *colorizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return colorizedImage;
}
```

However with this approach I run into an issue where if the bg of an image has a transparency the white below it shine through and it looks strange:

[image]

How can I detect the transparency and change the transparency to white? Or is there a better solution for doing this?

```
image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake((self.collectionViewContainer.frame.size.width/3),90)];
UIImage *unSelected = [self colorizeImage:image withColor:[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.9]];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:unSelected highlightedImage:image];
```

Comment: In the McDonads? image, do you want the white area to appear gray at all?

Comment: You could add a UIView that has a black or gray background and add it directly above your UIImageView.  You could change the alpha for varying levels of transparency.  Make sure the opaque property of the UIView is set to NO.

Comment: @rmaddy I want all images to have the same shading. So yea i do want the white area to be gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you simply want to apply a gray tint to an image, try it this way:

```
- (UIImage *)colorizeImage:(UIImage *)image withColor:(UIColor *)color {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size, NO, image.scale);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    [image drawInRect:area];

    [color set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, area);

    UIImage *colorizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return colorizedImage;
}
```

This draws the image and then draws the color over the image. Assuming the color is partially transparent, the entire new image will be colored.

As you had it originally, you were only coloring the non-transparent parts due to the image clipping.

This update also applies the proper scale to the new image to match the original image.